# Filter the list in sharepoint online?

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, site-collection, custom-list, office-365

I have a sharepoint list . There are 4 people(not fixed) from separate groups(say A,B) responsible for each issue. Now I've a requirement according to which,

1. I'll have to design a page display the list based on the login user.(this is one success)
2. Also, there is a group B which is the group with the highest permissions and will be able to see all the list items without filter.

Comment: Why don't you try to make web-part which uses CAML Query show them as per log in user

Comment: Thanks you very much..... But my problem is List is filtered by as per log in user using the filters , When Group 'E' log in we need to display all records without filter.  Its very urgent .

Comment: Yup you can do that same as u require by web-part and CAML Query

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to make use of audience in SharePoint. Add the different groups or members that need to have issues filtered in different ways. Then add App Parts to the page.

[image]

You can add more than one App Part of the same list, assigning different audiences and filters the way you want.

[image]

When you have all the App Parts in place, add audience to each App Part.

[image]

Edit the current view of each App Part according to your preference.

[image]

Users only see the App Part which is targeted to the audience she is a member of, and filtered the way you prefer.

I guess that solves your problem? If not, please tell me what more you need to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

You could either go with multiple App-parts and use audiances like Benny sugested or take advantage of "Me" in the filter like described down under. The advantage of using "Me" is that if someone new comes around and gets issues/tasks assigned to them you wont have to make a New App-part and go through with the audiance-procedure.

Using 1 App-part for infinite personal views:

[image: ..]

Edit: To clarify i still sugest 2x App-parts with audiances, But use sharepoint security-groups for this rather than single users.

So App-part1 is for Personal Issues and App-part2 is for Manager-overlook.

- Part1 audiance: users
- Part2 audiance: managers